# How to retrieve certain properties of an array of objects and put it into a new array of objects?

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects like below,

```
data: [
    {
      name: 'name1',
      id: '1',
      description: 'name 1 description',
    }, 
    {
      name: 'name2',
      id: '2',
      description: 'name 2 description',
    },
    {
      name: 'name3',
      id: '3',
      description: 'name 3 description',
    },
]
```

i have an array consisting of ids like so

```
const id_list = ['1','2'];
```

Now i want to retrieve the id and name from data array object whose id matches with id_list

so the expected output is

```
const new = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'name1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'name2',
  }
]
```

i am new to using react, javascript or typescript. could someone help me solve this. thanks.

**what i have tried?**

i know that to filter the value based on one value

so if i have to filter based on one id say '1'
i can do

const new =  data.filter((item) => id === item.id);

but in my case i want to filter all items which match the id_list array and should retrieve only matching object name and id and put it to a array.

Comment: `const newArr = id_list.map(id => data.find(item => item.id === id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with a [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to map every id of `id_list` to the corresponding object in `data`

```js
const result = id_list.map((id) => data.find((d) => d.id === id));
```

After that you have all objects that were found by ids in `result`. You can either only use the props you want or map again and get only the required properties.

```js
const final = result.map(({ id, name })=> ({ id, name }))
```